# How to use Resharper to transform Parameters to Object Initializer

Tags: c#, resharper

I like the feature "Transform Parameters" very much.

In some cases, I would like to transform parameters to object initializer instead of constructors in order to avoid long parameters.

This is the example code

```cs
namespace Test.Test
{
    public class TestUtility
    {
        public void Example()
        {
            this.GetTest("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5");
        }

        public void GetTest(string a1, string a2, string a3, string a4, string a5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{a1}\t{a2}\t{a3}\t{a4}\t{a5}");
        }
    }
}
```

and what I want is:

```cs
namespace Test.Test
{
    public class TestUtility
    {
        public void Example()
        {
            // this is how Resharper generated
            // this.GetTest(new TestClass("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"));

            // what I want
            this.GetTest(new TestClass
            {
                A1 = "a1",
                A2 = "a2",
                A3 = "a3",
                A4 = "a4",
                A5 = "a5"
            });
        }

        public void GetTest(TestClass testClass)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{testClass.A1}\t{testClass.A2}\t{testClass.A3}\t{testClass.A4}\t{testClass.A5}");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to produce it with either R# or Rider - so it doesn't seem to be supported.

Maybe you can create a ticket at JetBrains so that they can track it as a feature request.